# Vue.js 3 use autofocus on input with ref inside a method

Tags: vue.js, focus, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I worked with Vue2, but I recently try Vue 3.

I have simple problem:

```
 <input ref="myinput" />
 <button @click="submitData" />
```

I want to set "focus" on "myinput", inside function "submitData".
In Vue 2 it is simple (this.$refs ...), but in Vue 3, they made it complicated.
I saw example with "setup", but is no use for me + I think you can only access "value" from element.

Is there any way to execute "focus" on on element inside methods?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are still able to do the same thing using Vue 3, but if you work with composition api there's some difference :

**Options API :**

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {

  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitData() {
      this.$refs.myinput.focus()
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Vue 3 app
  <input ref="myinput" />
  <button @click="submitData">
  Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

**composition API:**

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
  onMounted,

} = Vue;
const App = {

  setup() {
    const myinput = ref(null)

    function submitData() {
      myinput.value.focus()
    }

    return {
      myinput,
      submitData
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Vue 3 app
  <input ref="myinput" />
  <button @click="submitData">
  Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you try it?

Comment: Very similar to how its displayed in your answer. I get undefined when trying to log the value of the `ref` item

Comment: please provide an example to check it

Comment: @RizaKhan, in my case, I need to hard reload the page to make it work.

Comment: submitData in the example should be onMounted?

Comment: @anthonygore If you want to focus  on the input at the first rendering you could set it inside onMounted but if you want to call using the click event there's no need to call it there

Answer (score 30):

In case someone comes to this question looking for a way to set the autofocus of a specific element in Vue3, you can achieve it using a [Vue Custom Directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#intro)

```js
const { createApp, onMounted } = Vue;

const app = createApp({})

// Register a global custom directive called `v-focus`
app.directive('focus', {
  // When the bound element is mounted into the DOM...
  mounted(el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input />
    <input v-focus />
    <input />
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

In some cases when the input is hidden under a v-show or v-if it is necessary to do a nextTick for the focus to work.

```html
<span
    v-show="!editMode"
    @click="handleEditionMode"
>
    {{ content }}
</span>
<input
    v-show="editMode"
    ref="input"
    v-model="content"
    aria-describedby="item-content"
    name="content"
    type="text"
    tabindex="0"
    @focusout="editMode = false"
    @keydown.enter="editMode = false"
/>
```

```js
const input = ref(null),
    editMode = ref(false);

const handleEditionMode = () => {
    editMode.value = true;
    nextTick(() => {
        input.value.focus();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I have been pulling my hair out over this issue, and this was exactly what was missing from my puzzle.

Comment: This is the right answer with Vue 3. Don't forget to import the nextTick function at the top of the file (`import { nextTick } from 'vue'`)

Comment: Ran into this exact issue focusing a ref on `onMounted()` in Vue 3. The docs on nextTick() offer some explanation, but really wish it wasn't such a magical black box fix.

Answer (score 10):

Easiest answer I found is missing here

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

Comment: This will only work on first page load, or when reloading a page.

Comment: Yes, this will only work on page (re)load. But it is the right solution if you want to have an element focused initially on loading the page.

Comment: For the vuejs this is not a appropriate solution. :(

Answer (score 2):

**onMounted** didn't work for me I used **watchEffect**:

```
<script setup>
   import { ref, watchEffect} from 'vue'

// declare a ref to hold the element reference
// the name must match template ref value
    
    const input = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
    watchEffect(() => {
        if (input.value) {
            input.value.focus()
        }
    });

</script>

<template>
  <input ref="input" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another vanilla solution is:

`document.getElementById("code")?.focus()`

to be called on `onMounted`

Answer (score 1):

In the Vue 3 Composable API I found the most straightforward solution was to use document.getElementById().  The trick was to wrap the .focus() call in Vue's nextTick()

```
/** set focus to predetermined HTML element  */
const setFocusToElement = async () => {
  nextTick(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById('myInputId');
    if (element) {
      element.focus();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: getElementById is fantastic, the problem with this solution is that getElementById looks for the element in the whole document, if you have more than one instance of your component, you need to identify the element of a specific instance of the component. Not just an element with a certain id or class

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to select a specific input upon loading the form component.

The above examples were not useful, so I figured it out myself.

This is far simpler, IMHO. Add 1 ref tag and 1 line of code in the mounted hook.

Place a ref tag on the item you'd like to focus. Here I named it "formStart" but you can name yours whatever you like.

```html
<form @submit.prevent="createNewRoute">
  <label for="code">Code</label>
  <input v-model="code" id="code" type="text" ref="formStart" /> <!-- REF TAG HERE -->
  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <input v-model="type" id="type" type="text" />
  /* Other inputs hidden for simplicity */
  <button type="submit">Add Route</button>
</form>
```

Reference that ref tag in the `mounted` hook and `focus()` it.

```js
<script>
export default {
  /* Other options hidden for simplicity */
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.formStart.focus(); // FOCUS ELEMENT HERE
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div
            v-if="openmodal"
            tabindex="0"
            v-focus
            @keydown.right="() => nextimage(1)"
        >
       </div>
```

i used methods of @webcu and added tabindex="0" it's work!