# set focus on input field in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form in which I want to set focus on the input field.
here is the html of form:

```
<form method="GET" name="searchFormArticles" novalidate="" data-search-form="articles" data-search-form-articles="" action="/rechtstipps" id="searchFormArticles" data-read-only="1">
  <input type="text" name="what" id="searchArticlesWhat" placeholder="Thema / Autor / Titel" class="form-control anw-form-control border-left-0 anw-md-rounded-right-none anw-md-border-right-0 shadow-none form-control" value="" autocomplete="off">

<button name="searchArticles" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-3 mt-md-0 shadow-none text-nowrap py-md-0 px-9 anw-md-rounded-left-none">
  <i class="far fa-search d-none d-md-inline-block text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Suchen</span>
</button>
```

input field has a name=what attribute and a id attribute as well, how can I catch this input element in vue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64774113/8172857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give autofocus property in the first input field.

```
<input type="text" name="what" id="searchArticlesWhat" placeholder="Thema / Autor / Titel" class="form-control anw-form-control border-left-0 anw-md-rounded-right-none anw-md-border-right-0 shadow-none form-control" value="" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

Comment: I cant add that, I have to jump the focus to the input field after a particular event

Comment: Then you can try 
``document.getElementById("searchArticlesWhat").focus();``

Comment: have a look at this chunk of code :

formsWhat.forEach(form => {

        if (form.getAttribute('data-search-form') === currentSearchType) {

          form.reset();

          /-----here I want to set focus to input field-----/

         
        }
      });

after reseting the form I want to set focus the input field inside the form

Comment: After ``form.reset();`` you can get Element by ``id`` and set focus on it.
using ``document.getElementById("searchArticlesWhat").focus();``

Comment: How can I get to the field ??  the whole form is inside the "form" object

Comment: ``form.elements[1].focus()``

Comment: you mean form.elements[0].focus(), Thank you so much Huzaifa bro, it worked like a charm, Shukriya :)